# Having issue in revoke apple sign in token in react native

Tags: ios, react-native, apple-sign-in

I am trying to revoke token in apple sign in in react native. But saying

```
{error: 'invalid_client'}
```

The above issue i am getting while running a network call

```
https://appleid.apple.com/auth/token
```

The data  i am sending is this(follow below image):
[image: The data i am passing]
Please have a look and let me know where i am making a mistake. Thanks